# Nativescript + Angular. Content under StatusBar

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

In newly created NativeScript + Angular app I have an issue on iOS that content of root StackLayout spans behind the StatusBar. Is there any property that would adjust app's content to some sort of frame with StatusBar excluded? So that app content starts after StatusBar.

Comment: you could add a top margin/padding?

Comment: Are you using a `page-router-outlet` or it's just the StackLayout on your app component?

Comment: @Manoj I do use page-router-outlet, though the component is in lazy loaded module

Comment: Could you please share a Playground sample where we can reproduce the issue.